# Remove double quotes from JSON returned string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have an ajax method that returns an MVC JsonResult. I use the data to populate a 3rd party controls datasource. The 3rd party control is expecting the data to not be a string (i.e. with no double quotes around it). If I alert the data returned in the jquery ajax call, It shows no double quotes:

```
[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [90, 100]]
```

However if I look at the data through fidler it shows my data to be inside double quotes:

> "[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60,
>   70], [70, 80], [90, 100]]"

The 3rd party control is not setting the datasource correctly, and I am sure it is because of this (If I populate the datasource by hardcoding the above data, it works fine)

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`ing (or `$.parseJSON`) the returned data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use eval() or JSON.parse()

```
var array = eval("[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [90, 100]]");

var array = JSON.parse("[[10, 10], [15, 20], [20, 25], [32, 40], [43, 50], [55, 60], [60, 70], [70, 80], [90, 100]]");
```

Comment: You should prefer `JSON.parse` (or even `$.parseJSON`) over `eval`.

Comment: if your browser doesn't support JSON, use json2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 2):

The JSON returned from the server is a string. It's not possible for the server to send Javascript objects.

If the control needs a Javascript object, then you need to parse the string. You can use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the string and create a Javascript object from it, or better yet use a method like [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to get it or specify `daraType: 'json'` in the [`@.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options, then the string will automatically be parsed before the `success` callback function is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data with $.getJSON instead of ajax, it will return as an object instead of string.

```
$.getJSON('your/ajax/url', function(json){ ...your code here...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this format, add float in your number value

```
$json[]=    array($row[0],(float)$row[1],(float)$row[2]);
```